# Directly reaching SessionId from the .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net

When I tried to get the SessionId of the user session in aspx page like below, it returns nothing

**default.aspx**

```
Session ID : <% Session.SessionID.ToString(); %>
```

but if I use a literal and try to assign sessionId to it in the page_load, it works. So which lifecycle step that aspx page is being loaded to the page ? Why this happening ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (note the equal sign and no semicolon):

```
Session ID : <%= Session.SessionID.ToString() %>
```

...and this list of server tags will help you in the future:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1139381/1828702.aspx#1828702